# How to portably use system or popen, but with array of arguments?

Tags: c, popen, argv

system/popen - portable, but uses shell - one string argument

pipe+fork+dup2+exec - more code, less portable, but can specify the array.

Is there something simple in middle? Expecting something like:

```
const char* args = {"/usr/bin/myprogram", "myprogram", "--option", NULL};
FILE* outfile = popen_read_end_args(args);
fscanf(outfile, "...");
fclose(outfile);
```

What is the best way to call external program using array and read its output in C? Are there any nonbloated wrappers for this?

Comment: `popenv()` and `systemv()`, by analogy with `execv()`?  Interesting idea.  A fallback implementation would simply convert the arguments to a single string and call the standard function (though 'simply' might be a bit casual; you'd need to ensure things were properly quoted).  You could then implement your own version as time permits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented such wrapper myself: https://github.com/vi/udpserv/blob/master/popen_arr.c

Here's the header file:

```
/**
* For and exec the program, enabling stdio access to stdin and stdout of the program
* You may close opened streams with fclose.
* Note: the procedure does no signal handling except of signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
* You should waitpid for the returned PID to collect the zombie or use signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
*
* @arg in stdin of the program, to be written to. If NULL then not redirected
* @arg out stdout of the program, to be read from. If NULL then not redirected
* @arg program full path of the program, without reference to $PATH
* @arg argv NULL terminated array of strings, program arguments (includiong program name)
* @arg envp NULL terminated array of environment variables, NULL => preserve environment
* @return PID of the program or -1 if failed
*/
int popen2_arr (FILE** in, FILE** out, const char* program, const char* argv[], const char* envp[]);

/** like popen2_arr, but uses execvp/execvpe instead of execve/execv, so looks up $PATH */
int popen2_arr_p(FILE** in, FILE** out, const char* program, const char* argv[], const char* envp[]);

/**
* Simplified interface to popen2_arr.
* You may close the returned stream with fclose.
* Note: the procedure does no signal handling except of signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
* You should wait(2) after closing the descriptor to collect zombie process or use signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)
*
* @arg program program name, can rely on $PATH
* @arg argv program arguments, NULL-terminated const char* array
* @arg pipe_into_program 1 to be like popen(...,"w"), 0 to be like popen(...,"r")
* @return FILE* instance or NULL if error
*/
FILE* popen_arr(const char* program, const char* argv[], int pipe_into_program);
```

Comment: Could you comment a little on the platform portability of this code (where you've run this on)? It looks pretty nice and I am looking to adapt it for my purposes. I'm trying to convert code from using `popen` because it annoys me that it's spawning a shell, but would prefer not to get too dirty with `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's isn't. ISO C has no other way of starting a new process than through `system`. POSIX has no other ways of starting a process than `system`, `popen` and `fork` (+ `vfork` before POSIX.2008).

Comment: Is there some simple library that does just this?

Comment: @Vi.: not a "semi-standard" one that I'm aware of. You could grab the source code for `popen` from BSD, then hack it to take the kind of arguments you're looking for. E.g. the OpenBSD version is [here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/gen/popen.c).